# Flex 4.5 alert message for textInput

Tags: validation, actionscript-3, apache-flex, alert, flex4.5

Created two textfield and I have to validate it and display the error msg in the alert box.
In 4.5 mx.controls.Alert is not supported. I tried including mx from the source path. Kindly help me how to show the alert box by validating the textfield is empty..

```
<code>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="validation">



<fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Component className="AlertMsg">
            <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer x="70" y="100">
                <s:TitleWindow title="My Message" close="close()">
                    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                        <s:Label text="My alert message text here..."/>
                        <s:Button label="OK" click="close()"/>
                    </s:VGroup>
                </s:TitleWindow>
            </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
        </fx:Component>
    </fx:Declarations>



    <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" gap="10"
                              horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="top"/>
        </s:layout>

    <s:TextInput id="firstName"/>
    <s:TextInput id="zipCodeInput"/>
    <s:Button label="Show Alert" click="(new AlertMsg()).open(this, false)"/>

</s:View>

</code>
```

Here alert is displayed in fx:declaration. How to show the alert msg by validating the textfield.. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a click handler on your button "Show Alert" instead of directly showing your alert box. From there, validate the value of your `TextInput` fields. If it's empty, show your alert.

```
<fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[        
      private function validateField() : void {
          if (firstName.text == "" || zipCodeInput.text == "")
              new AlertMsg().open(this, false);
      }
   ]]>   
</fx:Script>


<s:Button label="Show Alert" click="validateField()"/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to display alert without SkinnablePopUpContainer in flex 4.5

Comment: yes it is. you can use `TitleWindow` BUT remember it's not `mobile-optimized`. if your app is for mobile, just stick to `SkinnablePopupContainer`. :)

Comment: App is for mobile. I will use SkinnablePopupContainer. Thanks Rui